Nearest exit from an entrance in a maze
I am trying to solve the following question
https://leetcode.com/problems/nearest-exit-from-entrance-in-maze/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=leetcode-75
This is my approach
def insidemaze(r,c,nrow,ncol,grid):
    if (( r>=0 and r<= nrow-1 and c>=0 and c<=ncol-1)) :
        return True
    return False    


def isboundary(r,c,nrow,ncol,grid):
    if ( r== 0 or r==nrow-1 or c== 0 or c==ncol-1) :
        return True 



class Solution:
    def nearestExit(self, maze: List[List[str]], entrance: List[int]) -> int:
        
        queue = collections.deque()
        queue.append([entrance[0],entrance[1],0])

        dirs = ((1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1))
        maze[entrance[0]][entrance[1]] = "+"

        nrow = len(maze)
        ncol = len(maze[0])

        while queue :
            print("queue =" , queue)
            a = queue.popleft()
            maze[a[0]][a[1]] = "+"
            for dir in dirs :
                b = [ a[0] + dir[0] , a[1] + dir[1] ]
                print("b=",b)
                if (insidemaze(b[0],b[1],nrow,ncol,maze) ) :
                    if (isboundary(b[0],b[1],nrow,ncol,maze) and (maze[b[0]][b[1]] == "." ) ) :
                        return(a[2]+1)
                    else :
                        if maze[b[0]][b[1]] == "." :
                            queue.append([b[0],b[1],a[2]+1])
                        else:
                            print("do nothing")    
        return(-1)

I am using BFS to find a solution and this is the most optimized approach that I can think of, yet this gives the error

Time limit exceeded

when there are large input values. How can I improve the speed?

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.


You don't need the last else. Already, you have the return statements.

Also, if and else statements are not necessary for insidemaze() and isboundary().



def insidemaze(r, c, nrow, ncol):
    return 0 <= r < nrow and 0 <= c < ncol


def isboundary(r, c, nrow, ncol):
    return r == 0 or r == nrow - 1 or c == 0 or c == ncol - 1


class Solution:
    def nearestExit(self, maze: List[List[str]], entrance: List[int]) -> int:
        queue = collections.deque()
        queue.append([entrance[0], entrance[1], 0])

        dirs = ((1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1))
        maze[entrance[0]][entrance[1]] = "+"

        nrow = len(maze)
        ncol = len(maze[0])

        while queue:
            a = queue.popleft()
            for dir in dirs:
                b = [a[0] + dir[0], a[1] + dir[1]]
                if insidemaze(b[0], b[1], nrow, ncol):
                    if maze[b[0]][b[1]] == ".":
                        if isboundary(b[0], b[1], nrow, ncol):
                            return a[2] + 1
                        maze[b[0]][b[1]] = "+"
                        queue.append([b[0], b[1], a[2] + 1])

        return -1


Note

You need to add maze[b[0]][b[1]] = "+", prior to appending the neighbor to the queue.

